# Problem with error (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm writing a SystemVerilog assignment to simulate a logic circuit, and the following errors occur. I cannot understand how to deal with it.  Please help.

These are the error messages:

```
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(8): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "A".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(8): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "B".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(8): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "C".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(10): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "A".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(10): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "B".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(10): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "C".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(12): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "A".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(12): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "B".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(12): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "C".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(14): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "A".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(14): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "B".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(14): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "C".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(16): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "A".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(16): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "B".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(16): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "C".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(18): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "A".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(18): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "B".
** Error: E:/ModelSim File/work/1c.sv(18): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "C".
```

this is my code:

```
module biii (input logic A,B,C,
output logic F);
assign F = ~(~(A & C) & (B & ~(C)));
endmodule

module t_1c(input logic A,B,C,
output logic F);
biii B2(A,B,C,F);

initial begin

#20
A=0;B=0;C=0;
#20
A=0;B=1;C=0;
#20
A=0;B=0;C=1;
#20
A=1;B=1;C=0;
#20
A=1;B=0;C=0;
#20
A=0;B=1;C=0;
#20;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `t_1c` module looks like a testbench.  In that case, you do not need to declare the signals as module ports.  The errors mean that you cannot make an assignment to a signal declared as an `input` port inside a module.  Change:

```
module t_1c(input logic A,B,C,
output logic F);
```

to:

```
module t_1c;

logic A,B,C,F;
```